# How to make Utility Methods for Thread

Tags: c#, thread-safety, volatile

I want to make a re-usable piece of code that Threads can call to sleep until a certain time has been reached or they are told to cancel. The Cancel variable would be a volatile Boolean on the object that has the Thread.

My approach was this:

```
public class ThreadUtil
{
    public static void SleepTillOrDone(DateTime till, ref bool done)
    {
        while ((!done) && (DateTime.Now < till))
        {
            var diff = till - DateTime.Now;
            Thread.Sleep(diff.TotalMilliseconds >= 100 ? 100 : 10);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gives a warning of "a reference to a volatile field will not be treated as volatile". After reading around a bit I understand what the warning means, but how would one write such a method that would be safe to use without the volatile keyword? Or is there a different & completely better approach?

Comment: cancel variable? are you talking about the variable you are passing to the done parameter?

Comment: I think there is some important code missing here, and that is *what is it you're really trying to do*? What you're asking for is probably a sign that we could re-architect what you're trying to do a little and fix the problem as a whole.

Comment: @BigM: I have the same SleepTillTimeOrDone code in several different classes that each have their own flags for shutting down. I want to have the logic for this SleepTillTimeOrDone in one place and use it in all the other classes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you're trying to reinvent existing primitives. In this case, the WaitHandles. Your method looks a lot like [ManualResetEvent.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477.aspx) with a timeout in intent.